# How many Nginx processes should there be?

Tags: server, nginx, ps

Just installing Nginx on a fresh ubuntu server 12.04.

`ps -e | grep nginx`  at first returned nothing so i ran `nginx`which appeared to get things started.

Running  `ps -e | grep nginx` now returns a number of identical processes?

```
 1793 ?        00:00:00 nginx
 1794 ?        00:00:00 nginx
 1795 ?        00:00:00 nginx
 1796 ?        00:00:00 nginx
 1797 ?        00:00:00 nginx
```

Everything appears to be running, however I'm interested to know why there are multiples, what they're doing and what would happen to my server if I were to kill just one of them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the number of your **worker processes** of `nginx`. The default configuration has 4 worker processes. They are here that the web server can handle multiple connections very fast. One of them is the **master process** see the output of `ps fax | grep nginx`:

```
 user@host:~# ps fax | grep nginx
 6885 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
 6886 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
 6887 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
 6888 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
 6889 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

You see there is a master process and 4 child processes (workers).

Ot determine how many worker processes are configured type:

```
user@host:~# grep worker_processes /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
worker_processes 4;
```

Comment: Ah of course! I set it up with 4 workers! Duh. Thanks for the explanation!